# is it possible to return the array with object property names? it's wired to ask to print the string without ' '

Tags: javascript, json

Write a function called  myFun which has an object as its parameter and returns the name of properties of that object in an array. For instance, if it receives {a:1,b:3}, as its parameter,  it should return [a, b], or if it receives {u:4, k:3, h:5},  it should return [u, k, h].

**Note** I am aware of Object.Keys(object) returns ['a', 'b', 'c']

```
//this function should return the name of the property
function myFun(object) {
    object = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    }
    for (obj in object) {
        console.log(obj);
    }
}
    
myFun();

//testcase : console.log(myFun({a:6})[0]) which should return [a], is it 
 actually possible or am I asking the wrong question?
```

Comment: `Object.keys(object)`

Comment: if this is the 
myObj = {u:4, k:3, h:5};

I was trying to output [u, k, h]

while if I try Object.keys(myObj);
I get something like ['u', 'k', 'h'] I want to avoid ' ' 
if that make sense?

Comment: @MR.Stranger that _doesn't_ make sense. The keys are strings, you cant just have `[u,k,h]` because that is not a thing - u k & h are not defined. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an array of object keys:

```
const keys = Object.keys(object);
```

To print them like you describe:

```
console.log(`[${keys.join(',')}]`);
```

Putting it together as a function:

```
function myFun(object) {
    const keys = Object.keys(object);

    return `[${keys.join(',')}]`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @domenikk I assume this is one of the solution, could you please read the question and help me achieve this using a function, feel free to write a new piece of code and also ignore my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the  object's [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var obj = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
      };
      
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Comment: I just want to print [a, b, c], is it possible?

Comment: @MR.Stranger no, because that doesn't make sense - as I said above a, b & c are just undefined variables. What are you actually trying to do? You have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Write a function called  fun which has an object as its parameter and returns the name of properties of  that object in an array. For instance, if it receives {a:1,b:3}, as its parameter,  it should return [a, b], or if it receives {u:4, k:3, h:5},  it should return [u, k, h].

Comment: @MR.Stranger "**name** of properties" should be a pretty good indication that you want strings. names are always strings.

Comment: @MR.Stranger check my edited answer

Comment: haha yes I found this question as a warm up question for JavaScript and  It's bit strange when the question says "Name of the properties"(which are always strings) but wanted to display in [u, k, h]. Thanks for the help @Jamiec